# `before` hook inside of test case (`it`)

Tags: mocha.js

Does mocha not allow a hook inside of a `it` test case?

I tried the following and it seems to never execute:

```
describe('Array', () => {

  before(async () => {
      // do some async stuff before any test cases in this suite run
      // THIS RUNS OK
  });

  it('should blah', async () => {
      before(async () => {
          // do some async stuff just before this test case
          // THIS NEVER RUNS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      });

      // blah
  );

});
```

The `before` immediately in the `describe` runs, but the `before` immediately inside the `it` does not run.

Comment: This doesn't look like an appropriate usage of `before`. What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Why does a `before` _before_ the `it` not serve the purpose?

Comment: Yea it could easily, I just thought it should work in `it` as well. If it doesn't, then I'll no problem move it out to the `describe` `before`. I was just wondering if it is not supported inside `it`s.